# Merge Sorting fails to merge parts at the end of process

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, mergesort

I tried sorting with the ***simple case of***

```
test = {12, 11, 13, 5, 6};
```

It does the spliting and merging of subparts in lefthalf  and righthalf as

```
{11 12} & {5 6 13}
```

which is desired. **But during Final Merging** it takes lefthalf and righthalf as

```
{12 11} & {13 5 6}
```

And this gives the wrong answer of :

```
{12 11 13 5 6}
```

Why is this Happening ? Here is my code.

```
void mergesrt(deque<int> mydeq){
 if (mydeq.size() > 1){
    int mid = mydeq.size()/2;
    deque<int> lefthalf(mydeq.begin(), mydeq.begin() + mid);
    deque<int> righthalf(mydeq.begin() + mid, mydeq.begin() + mydeq.size());  
    mergesrt(lefthalf);
    mergesrt(righthalf);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    cout << "--------------merging-----------" << endl;

    while (i < lefthalf.size() && j < righthalf.size()){
     if (lefthalf[i] < righthalf[j]){
            mydeq[k] = lefthalf[i];
            k++;
            i++;
     }
     else{
           mydeq[k] = righthalf[j];
           k++;
           j++;
           }
          }

     while (i < lefthalf.size()){
            mydeq[k] = lefthalf[i];
            k++;
            i++;
            }

     while (j < lefthalf.size()){
            mydeq[k] = righthalf[j];
            k++;
            j++;
            }
           }

       return;
       }
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: I am sure that he has already debugged to provide relevant intermediate input and output @NathanOliver

Comment: Find a small failing example. Try the algorithm by hand with pen and paper. If on paper the error does not occur, compare the steps with a debugger and find out this way where the computer does something different form your pen and paper execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is subtle and not easily noticed by new developers.  You're passing your argument to `mergsrt` by value, which means a copy is made.  The sorting is done on this copy, and the original deque is not changed.  You need to pass by reference (`mergsrt(deque<int> &)`) instead.

Comment: And It Worked ! Thanks a lot.